# Missing sudo password in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Ansible asks for sudo password from following code, it tries to create a new postgres user.

Error message:

> fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => Missing sudo password

main.yml

```
- name: 'Provision a PostgreSQL server'
  hosts: "dbservers"
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  roles:
    - postgres
```

create_db.yml

```
- name: Make sure the PostgreSQL users are present
  postgresql_user: name=rails password=secret role_attr_flags=CREATEDB,NOSUPERUSER
  sudo_user: postgres
  sudo: yes
```

The remote_user that used to login to this machine is a **non-root** user, it has no password, and can only login using key auth.

For user **postgres**, this account doesn't have the password as well, because the database was just installed.

Since I logged in as **non**-root user, of course it will ask for password when switch to **postgress** account in order to create database user. But it won't be need for password if switch to **postgres** from root account. So, I wonder if there is a way to switch to root, and then switch to user **postgres**.

Note: the root account has no public key, no password, and cannot login from SSH.

Answer (score 167):

Try with the option `-kK`. It will prompt for password.

```
$ ansible-playbook mail.yml -kK 
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:
```

- **-k, --ask-pass**: ask for connection password
- **-K, --ask-become-pass**: ask for privilege escalation password

Also `sshpass` program must be installed.

In Debian based system

```
$ sudo apt install sshpass
```

Comment: or long ``--ask-become-pass``

Comment: i have an inventory that combines auth with ssh_private_key and password auth. I get this output and I just have to hit enter `BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:`

Comment: This is IMO the best answer. No tinkering with the sudoers file is a big plus.

Comment: If  ssh key copied to remote machine, `--ask-pass` not necessary as we connect to remote machine with key exchange method. Only use `--ask-become-pass` to enter remote machine password.

Answer (score 38):

You can specificy the sudo password when running the Ansible playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=yourPassword"
```

Comment: it's not a good idea to put your sudo password on command line

Comment: you can just set to True "become_ask_pass" in ansible.cfg, and the system will prompt for it. Or, if you want to fully automate it, use, for example, Ansible Vault to avoid this, saving the become password in an encrypted file, just need to add --ask-vault-pass (or some other mechanism, as saving the vault password itself in a hidden file your home dir, with access permissions just for you)...

Answer (score 26):

Add a file to the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory on the target machine called postgres with the following contents:

```
postgres ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

This ensures that the postgres user (provided you are using that as your sudo user) will not be asked for a password when it attempts sudo commands.

If you are using a different user to connect to the target machine, then you'll have to amend the above to give the NOPASSWD permission to that user instead.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password) for further details.

Comment: In my scenario same add the user in sudoers not work, still ask me the password, I gues this weird.
I'm using:

ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/myuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) [GCC 9.3.0]

Comment: I think there are more (and more secure) ways than adding NOPASSWD (that might be against some organizations' security policies): you can just set to True "become_ask_pass" in ansible.cfg, and the system will prompt for it. Or, if you want to fully automate it, use, for example, Ansible Vault to avoid this, saving the become password in an encrypted file, just need to add --ask-vault-pass, or some other mechanism, as saving the vault password itself in a hidden file your home dir, with access permissions just for the Ansible become user...

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I added the information to the servergroup's group variables

So in /etc/ansible/group_vars/{servergroup}/vars

I added

```
ansible_become: yes 
ansible_become_method: sudo
ansible_become_pass: "{{ vault_ansible_password }}"
```

This article helped me workout the answer https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-and-use-sudo-password-for-ansible-vault/

Answer (score 11):

You would need to modify `/etc/sudoers` file or command `visudo` to allow user with which you connect to the remove server to switch to another user without password prompt.

Comment: I was using the supervisorctl module, and my `/etc/sudoers` file was  configured to allow me to run the `sudo supervisorctl` without a password. The way ansible executes it, that isn't enough, you need to be able to change users. My work around was to run `command: sudo supervisorctl ...` directly without any module support.

Comment: I think there are more (and more secure) ways: you can just set to True "become_ask_pass" in ansible.cfg, and the system will prompt for it. Or, if you want to fully automate it, use, for example, Ansible Vault to avoid this, saving the become password in an encrypted file, just need to add --ask-vault-pass, or some other mechanism, as saving the vault password itself in a hidden file your home dir, with access permissions just for the Ansible become user...

Answer (score 5):

If all of the above solutions did not work for you, which was my case. My problem was that my ansible_user has not all the permissions, I don't like to allow root to connect from ssh.

But my tester user did not have all the sudo permissions to perform some operations:
Initial tester_user permission:

```
tester ALL= NOPASSWD:ALL     # bad
```

changed to :

```
tester ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL    # good
```

The meaning of these additional fields is:
First “ALL” indicates that the user can run commands as all users.
The second “ALL” indicates that the user can run commands as all groups.

Initially wanted to restrict permissions for maintainers, but it is mandatory that the ansible_user can run commands as all users use become_user in Ansible.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your /etc/sudoers file

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
username-u-want-to-allow        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my user did not have sudo permission on the managed node. By default ansible was setting the become_method: sudo
I found out this by specifying -vvvv, and looking at the logs.

```
...
remote_user: username
become_method: sudo
inventory: (u'/etc/ansible/hosts',)
...
```

ansible-playbook -u  -b ansible-script.yml  -vvvv

To get around the problem, I specify "become no" in the ansible script.
For example:

```
- name: Ensure the httpd service is running
  service:
    name: httpd
    state: started
  become: no
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Remote-server (Client-Server) or (target-server) whatever you call, as a root user write this command

> visudo pressenter
> Under

## User privilege specification

<your-name on (client-server)> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
save file
Now from your Controller-Server (Workstation) or (Ansible-Server) whatever you call, run your command

> ssh <your-user on (client-server)>@ipaddress
> SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

You don't need specify the *sudo_user* if the ssh_user that you use to make the connection belongs to the sudoers group, only has to say the *sudo_pass*.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen from Ansible Tower UI if you select the 'Enable Privilege Escalation' option. You might need to supply the password twice in Ansible Tower.

Answer (score 0):

My solution / workaround for error message:
fatal: [node]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

For me although the user already existed in the sudoers file on the remote host to perform commands without the use of password I still got this message. What I did to enter in the main YAML playbook enter:

```
---

- hosts: [your targeted inventory list of hosts]
  become_user: [your remote privileged user]
  become: true
  roles:
  - [your playbook role]
```

Also in the /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg I enabled/ commented out or changed the following:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=sudo
become_user=root
become_ask_pass=False

[defaults]
remote_tmp = /tmp/ansible-$USER
host_key_checking = False
sudo_user      = [your remote privileged user]
ask_sudo_pass = False
ask_pass      = False
```

The entry **remote_tmp = /tmp/ansible-$USER** was to avoid messages like:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/.ansible_tmpLyoZOOyum.conf'
fatal: [node]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The destination directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user. Error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/.ansible_tmpLyoZOOyum.conf'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have solved it by adding the command `/bin/sh` in the line of `/etc/sudoers` to allow executing commands without password.

This was the error shown:

```
BECOME password: 
debian | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to debian9 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Only add this:

```
user    ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/id, /usr/bin/whoami, /bin/sh
```

for testing purposes I also added `id` and `whoami`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even though password was correct, I was getting this error because playbook had "connection: local" specified.  The playbook had connection type set to local as all commands were supposed to be run on localhost.  After adding a new task which required delegation to remote host, the connection method was still set to local which resulted in the Missing sudo password error.  The error was fixed by removing the "connection: local" in playbook.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that after fixing the permissions, it still used previous session. Once I've deleted `.ansible_ssh_cp/` it worked OK