# fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}

Tags: docker, ansible

hello everyone i have a problem which is , i can't run an ansible playbook from aws instance (ansible system) to another aws (docker system) instance

it shows me this error

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
```

can any one help me please , i will be grateful

Comment: Your problem is that you (pick one or more) did not provide a password for sudo / did not install/configure sudo correctly on the target / did not configure your inventory correctly to access your target. You can start by providing the sudo password on the command line using the `--ask-become-pass` option to `ansible[-playbook]`. This should get you going before you take the appropriate actions [after reading the doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually i didn't get your scenario very well,do you want to connect to docker container from your playbook?

if that is the case you can add ssh public key 'id_rsa.pub' (generate this file by the command `ssh-keygen` inside the instance from where you want to connect to docker) to authorized_keys file inside docker container. When shh keys are there you don't need a sudo password.

You can do this in either in Dockerfile or using [ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id)

if you are not using ssh, and having this error while running task with 'become: true' or 'become: sudo', then add the following line to /etc/sudoers list

```
<username> ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: The connection to the host is actually ok. The problem is with privilege escalation: `sudo` is requiring a password

Answer (score 8):

From: [Missing sudo password in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582740/missing-sudo-password-in-ansible)

You should give ansible-playbook the flag to prompt for privilege escalation password.

```
ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass
```

Answer (score -1):

add the user into `visudo` file on the host server some thing like this

```
{username} ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```